# TS: Sort Multiple Observeable Data

Tags: angular, typescript, sorting, observable

I need to implement the function getNavigationItems() which should return an array of static and remote navitems, sorted by title and the invalid items removed. I just can't figure out a way to get the data of both observables and sort there data/ remove invalid ones...

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Link } from './app.component';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NavigationService {

  private staticNavigationItems$: BehaviorSubject<Link[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Link[]>(null);
  private dynamicNavigationItems$: BehaviorSubject<Link[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Link[]>(null);

  constructor() {
    this.staticNavigationItems$.next([
      { title: 'M', route: 'm' },
      { title: 'A', route: 'a' },
      { title: undefined, route: 'x' },
      { title: 'B', route: 'b' },
      { title: 'H', route: null },
    ]);
    this.mockFetchNavigationItems();
  }

  public getNavigationItems(): any {
    // TODO: use static and remote navigation items sorted by title
    // and since the data is not curated well, please remove the invalid items
    
  }

  private mockFetchNavigationItems(): void {
    // as if it would come from an http request
    setTimeout(() => this.dynamicNavigationItems$.next([
      { title: 'C', route: 'c' },
      { title: 'Z', route: 'z' },
    ]), 500);
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize RxJs's `combineLatest`

```
export class AppComponent {
  private staticNavigationItems$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<
    any[]
  >(null);
  private dynamicNavigationItems$: BehaviorSubject<any[]> = new BehaviorSubject<
    any[]
  >(null);

  constructor() {
    this.staticNavigationItems$.next([
      { title: 'M', route: 'm' },
      { title: 'A', route: 'a' },
      { title: undefined, route: 'x' },
      { title: 'B', route: 'b' },
      { title: 'H', route: null },
    ]);
    // as if it would come from an http request
    setTimeout(
      () =>
        this.dynamicNavigationItems$.next([
          { title: 'C', route: 'c' },
          { title: 'Z', route: 'z' },
        ]),
      500
    );
    this.mockFetchNavigationItems();
  }

  public getNavigationItems(): any {
    // TODO: use static and remote navigation items sorted by title
    // and since the data is not curated well, please remove the invalid items
  }

  private mockFetchNavigationItems(): void {
    combineLatest([this.dynamicNavigationItems$, this.staticNavigationItems$])
      .pipe(filter((a, b) => !!(a && b)))
      .subscribe(([staticdata, dynamicData]) => {
        const merged = [...staticdata, ...dynamicData];
        // your sorting logic
      });
  }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ndsyrk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)